# view is not changed inside closure expression

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
@IBAction func createUser(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    userManager!.createUser( username.text, {
        println( "new user created" )
        self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated( true )
        self.callback!()
    })


}
```

but when this function is called, the view controller in not changed..

if i'll take the popToRootViewControllerAnimated outside the inner closure expression i.e.:

```
@IBAction func createUser(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    userManager!.createUser( username.text, {
        println( "new user created" )

        self.callback!()
    })

    self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated( true )
}
```

the view will be changed and all will work just fine..

any idea why?

Update:
Just to be clear.. I do call this expression from the createUser method and the println is priting "new user created".
Just the view is not changing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must change UI only on main thread. Since `popToRootViewControllerAnimated(...)` changes UI it should be called on main thread, you can wrap it in GCD call:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    if let nc = self.navigationController {
        nc.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not call until and unless the `createUser` method calls `closure`.Clousre are not called immediately.In `createUser` method we are just pasing the closure.It is responsibility of `createUser` to call the closure.You need to call the clousre by parameter in which closure is taking like this

```
createUser(userName:String,parameterNameWhichTakesClousre: () -> ()){

...  //other instructions
parameterNameWhichTakesClousre() //put this in `createUser` to call closure.
}
```

If you put `self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated( true )` outside clousre it will called immediately as it is in function and it will call immediately where you place.

Comment: Yes i know all of this. I'm calling this clousre from createUser and the print there is also printed.. Just the view didnt changed

Comment: Ohhh.. Try to put `navigationController` refrence in variable and than use in `clousre` not sure if this work.